# Moving Realm entities to another Package

Tags: android, realm

I am doing a big refactor in my Android app and I am moving the RealmObjects to another package. After I move the packages, The `Realm` database is not able to find those entities and throw an exception saying that I am trying to add new entities to the database.
I need to do a migration in this case? How can I move those entities without problem? I read that the package did not matter, only the name.

Comment: Do you use a class with `@RealmModule` you give to Realm configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with delete 'build' (See attached screenshot) directory and restart android studio with

> File->invalidate cache and restart->Invalidate and restart

[image: Delete 'build' directory]

Comment: helped to get rid of "migration is needed" error. But now I get another one `Schema validation failed due to the following errors` : `Property 'object_title.property' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'object_title'`